# Silverstripe loop over ALL children of the sitetree

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I´m trying to create a sitemap of all children of the sitetree. For some pages ShowInMenus is set to false. But still these pages should be shown in the sitemao. I know you can loop over all children of a page like this (ignoring ShowInMenus):

```
<% loop AllChildren %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

Can I do something similar on the top Level of the sitetree?

Thx,
Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i do not know any build in loop you can use for this but you can do in php

```
public function AllPagesWithParentIDZero() {
    return SiteTree::get()->filter('ParentID', 0);
}
```

and use in template

```
<% loop $AllPagesWithParentIDZero %>
    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: thx ajshort for cleaning it up - was late when i posted a answer.

Comment: could work, just have to filter out ErrorPages, I can check it soon. thx

Comment: foreach(SiteTree::get()->filter('ParentID', 0) as $RootPage), exactly what I needed, thanks @munomono